# ReSharper - Go to type result assembly order

Tags: c#, resharper

There are several projects in our solution and some of them contains classes with the exact same name. When using "Search everywhere/Go to type" feature via Ctrl+T, the result list seems to be in random order. I always end up in the wrong project when navigatig.

Is there any way to specify project priority in which the results show up?